# auzre databricks install an application but a command cannot be entered from the databricks notebook

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, azure-databricks

I am trying to install an application on Azure databricks from python3.

From the databricks notebook:

```
%sh
cd  /dbfs/my_path/app_files/my_app/ #( there is a makefile here)
make

Enter soft-link target file or directory for "lib/include/xxx_app_name" (return if not needed):
```

I cannot use shell to access azure databricks, how I can enter the necessary command for the interactive command line ?

thanks

Comment: Did you try python subprocess for commands execution?

Comment: That's not a programming question but rather a support request for some piece of software. In any case, be prepared with something like a [mcve] and read [ask].

Comment: This notebook shows how to compile C/C++ code and run it on a Spark cluster in Databricks: https://kb.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/python/run-c-plus-plus-python.html